# I am stuck trying to fix line 78

Tags: python, tkinter

I have completely redone my code, and I'm getting a syntax error at line 78, `pennies=float(int(pennies.get())*.01.format$(.2f)` at `pennies.get()`. The arrow is pointing to the period between pennies and get. I'm really new to this, and I can't figure out how to fix this error. I had a different code posted originally, but it was incorrect.

Code:

```
from tkinter import*

money=Tk()

money.title("The amount of Money on hand")
Label(money,text='****Please provide the money you have and hit, Compute:***').grid(row=0,columnspan=5)
Label(money,text='Pennies').grid(row=1,column=0)
Label(money,text='Nickels').grid(row=2,column=0)
Label(money,text='Dimes').grid(row=3,column=0)
Label(money,text='Quarters').grid(row=4,column=0)
Label(money,text='Half Dollar Coin').grid(row=5,column=0)
Label(money,text='Dollar Coin').grid(row=6,column=0)
Label(money,text='Cash Dollar').grid(row=7,column=0)
Label(money,text='Cash 5 Dollar').grid(row=8,column=0)
Label(money,text='Cash 10 Dollar').grid(row=9,column=0)
Label(money,text='Cash 20 Dollar').grid(row=10,column=0)

Button(money,text='Quit',command=money.destroy).grid(row=11,column=0,sticky=W,pady=5)

Pennies=Entry(money)
Pennies.grid(row=1,column=1)
Nickels=Entry(money)
Nickels.grid(row=2,column=1)
Dimes=Entry(money)
Dimes.grid(row=3,column=1)
Quarters=Entry(money)
Quarters.grid(row=4,column=1)
Half_Dollar_Coin=Entry(money)
Half_Dollar_Coin.grid(row=5,column=1)
Dollar_Coin=Entry(money)
Dollar_Coin.grid(row=6,column=1)
Cash_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_Dollar.grid(row=7,column=1)
Cash_5_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_5_Dollar.grid(row=8,column=1)
Cash_10_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_10_Dollar.grid(row=9,column=1)
Cash_20_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_20_Dollar.grid(row=10,column=1)

Label(money,text='Pennies Value $:').grid(row=1,column=2)
Label(money,text='Nickels Value $:').grid(row=2,column=2)
Label(money,text='Dimes Value $:').grid(row=3,column=2)
Label(money,text='Quarters Value $:').grid(row=4,column=2)
Label(money,text='Half Dollar Coin Value $:').grid(row=5,column=2)
Label(money,text='Dollar Coin Value $:').grid(row=6,column=2)
Label(money,text='Cash Dollar Value $').grid(row=7,column=2)
Label(money,text='Cash 5 Dollar Value $').grid(row=8,column=2)
Label(money,text='Cash 10 Dollar Value $:').grid(row=9,column=2)
Label(money,text='Cash 20 Dollar Value $:').grid(row=10,column=2)
Label(money,text='Total').grid(row=11,column=2)


Pennies=Entry(money)
Pennies.grid(row=1,column=3)
Nickels=Entry(money)
Nickels.grid(row=2,column=3)
Dimes=Entry(money)
Dimes.grid(row=3,column=3)
Quarters=Entry(money)
Quarters.grid(row=4,column=3)
Half_Dollar_Coin=Entry(money)
Half_Dollar_Coin.grid(row=5,column=3)
Dollar_Coin=Entry(money)
Dollar_Coin.grid(row=6,column=3)
Cash_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_Dollar.grid(row=7,column=3)
Cash_5_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_5_Dollar.grid(row=8,column=3)
Cash_10_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_10_Dollar.grid(row=9,column=3)
Cash_20_Dollar=Entry(money)
Cash_20_Dollar.grid(row=10,column=3)
Total=Entry(money)
Total.grid(row=11,column=3)

def total_result():
   Pennies=float(int(Pennies.get())*.01)
   Nickels=float(int(Nichols.get())*.05)
   Dimes=float(int(Dimes.get())*.10)
   Quarters=float(int(Quarters.get())*.25)
   Half_Dollar_Coin=float(int(Half_Dollar_Coin.get())*.50)
   Dollar_Coin=float(int(Dollar_Coin.get())*1)
   Cash_Dollar=float(int(Cash_Dollar.get())*1)
   Cash_5_Dollar=float(int(Cash_5_Dollar.get())*5)
   Cash_10_Dollar=float(int(Cash_10_Dollar.get())*10)
   Cash_20_Dollar=float(int(Cash_20_Dollar.get())*20)

result='Pennies' + 'Nickels' + 'Dimes' + 'Quarters' + 'Half_Dollar_Coin' + 'Dollar_Coin' + 'Cash_Dollar' +'Cash_5_Dollar' + 'Cash_10_Dollar' + 'Cash_20_Dollar'

Button(money,text='Compute',command=total_result).grid(row=11,column=1,sticky=E,pady=5)

def only_numeric_input(x):
   if e.isdigit():
      return True
   elif e=="":
      return True
   else:
      return True
Pennies.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Nickels.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Dimes.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Quarters.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Half_Dollar_Coin.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Dollar_Coin.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Cash_Dollar.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Cash_5_Dollar.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Cash_10_Dollar.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Cash_20_Dollar.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
```

I am going to try retyping it in Python while I am waiting for some help. Thanks!

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Now the error I'm getting is: File "C:/Users/jessi/change1.py", line 78, in total_result
    Pennies=float(int(Pennies.get())*.01)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Pennies' referenced before assignment

I know that means I need to define Pennies as global, but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to do that. Also, wouldn't that mean I need to do that for each one?

Comment: Even though you make them global variables, your code will only work once.  When `total_result()` is called second time, another exception will be raised because all `Entry` widgets have been changed to `float` variables which do not have `get()` function.

Comment: There are plenty of errors in this. Hard to fix without know what all you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Entrys for displaying the values you re-use the names from the input Entrys, losing the references to the input Entrys. I have instead renamed the Entrys for displaying the values to `Pennies_value` etc.

Again in the function `total_result()` you reassign the names for the input entrys, this time to reference the floats.

If you want to be able to make the calculation more than once you must first delet any contents from the Entrys. Then write the computed value to the Entrys.

The computation will not work if the input Entrys contain "", so you will have to convert the value to 0 in that case. I'm doing this with the expression:

```
int(Pennies.get() or 0)
```

which evaluates the return from `Pennies.get()`: if it is `False` ("") the `int()` function will use 0 instead.

Finally, when you calculate the total you have to get the values from the display Entrys. See example below:

```
from tkinter import*

money = Tk()

money.title("The amount of Money on hand")
Label(money,text='****Please provide the money you have and hit, Compute:***').grid(row=0, columnspan=5)
Label(money,text='Pennies').grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(money,text='Nickels').grid(row=2, column=0)

Button(money, text='Quit', command=money.destroy).grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5)

# Entrys for number of coins/bills
Pennies = Entry(money)
Pennies.grid(row=1, column=1)
Nickels = Entry(money)
Nickels.grid(row=2, column=1)

Label(money, text='Pennies Value $:').grid(row=1, column=2)
Label(money, text='Nickels Value $:').grid(row=2, column=2)
Label(money, text='Total').grid(row=11, column=2)

# Entrys for display of value of coins/bills
Pennies_value = Entry(money)
Pennies_value.grid(row=1, column=3)
Nickels_value = Entry(money)
Nickels_value.grid(row=2, column=3)
Total_value = Entry(money)
Total_value.grid(row=11, column=3)

def total_result():
    Pennies_value.delete(0, "end")  # Delete entry contents from pos 0 till "end"
    Pennies_value.insert(0, int(Pennies.get() or 0)*.01)    # Insert text at pos 0
    Nickels_value.delete(0, "end")
    Nickels_value.insert(0, int(Nickels.get() or 0)*.05)
    result = (float(Pennies_value.get()) +
              float(Nickels_value.get()))
    Total_value.delete(0, "end")
    Total_value.insert(0, result)

Button(money, text='Compute', command=total_result).grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=E, pady=5)

def only_numeric_input(e):
    if e.isdigit():
        return True
    elif e=="":
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Configure input Entrys validation
Pennies.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))
Nickels.configure(validate='key',validatecommand=(money.register(only_numeric_input),'%P'))

money.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since this is supposed to be a working example, window wont be shown without `money.mainloop()`. Also the validation function seems to be "wrong", the `else` block should return `False` , not sure if thats the effect you want.

Comment: @Cool Cloud: You are quite right. I have corrected my example.